# Does the rank(A) equal the dim(range(A))?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question dealing with rank-nullity theorem.  In an n x m matrix, I'm given the value of m and the nullity of A, performing m-nullity(A) will produce rank(A), but I'm asked for the dim(range(A)).  Is this the same value as rank(A)?

Thank you?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank($T$) is defined to be the dimension of the range of $T$, so you are correct.

Comment: It is not necessarily **the** definition. There are other ones such as the value $n$ of the dimension $n \times n$ of the largest submatrix with nonzero determinant.